# Use confirm() as a condition to if?

Tags: javascript

I have this function:

```
function RemoveProduct() {
    if (confirm("Poista?") == return true) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

When you click a "remove" button on the page, it should ask if it should remove a product, and if the answer is yes, it will remove it.

But as far as I know, I can't use another brackets on the if sentence conditions?
How this should be done?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

When you compare a return value to `true` you shouldn't use `return true`, just `true`:

```
function RemoveProduct() {
  if (confirm("Poista?") == true) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

You don't even need to do the comparison, as the result from `confirm` is a boolean value:

```
function RemoveProduct() {
  if (confirm("Poista?")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

And you don't even need the `if` statement, you can just return the result from `confirm`:

```
function RemoveProduct() {
  return confirm("Poista?");
}
```

Remember to use `return` when you use the function in an event. Example:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="return RemoveProduct();" />
```

Comment: Ok, here's the line I'm using, but it's not working properly. `beforeRemove : function RemoveProduct(){return confirm("Poista?")}` It asks about this, but doesn't care about the selection. beforeRemove is a callback that will be executed before removing anything from the shopping cart.

Comment: @ChristianNikkanen: If `beforeRemove` is a property in an object, the function is an anonymous function and shouldn't have a name: `beforeRemove: function() { return confirm("Poista?"); }`. (The language itself allows it, but how it is implemented varies between browsers, so it's best to avoid it.)

Comment: for semantic purposes when using an if statement with true and false to a boolean variable you use three equals instead of 2.

Answer (score 5):

> But as far as I know, I can't use another brackets on the if sentence
>   conditions?

There is nothing that prevents you from executing a function within an if condition.  That said, I always get all the arguments to my conditional settled before the if, for clarity and readability.

Here is your code greatly simplified.

```
var confirmed = confirm('whatever');
return confirmed;
```

Answer (score 5):

`confirm()` returns a boolean value and you can return that. Like so:

```
function RemoveProduct() {
    return confirm("Poista?");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

just use

```
<a onclick="return confirm('ARe sure want to remove');">remove</a>
```

Comment: How do I get this confirm in JavaScript, so if the confirm returns true, then tap another button with JavaScript.