# How to use JConfirm with conditionals?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jconfirm

Is it possible to use the JConfirm Plugin with if statements to show different buttons within a popup or will it just need to be hard coded?

I had planned in my head something like the following:

> if account activated
>
> -> yes, display a deactivate button
>
> -> no, display a activate button

Which would code up something like the following:

```
                $.confirm({
                    icon: 'fas fa-users',
                    title: 'User Account: $name',
                    content: 'What would you like to do with this account?',
                    buttons: {
                        View: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-info',
                            text: 'View Profile',
                            action: function () {
                                // Take them to a link
                            }
                        },
                        Upgrade: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-info',
                            text: 'Upgrade to Tutor',
                            action: function () {
                                $.alert('Account successfully upgraded!');
                            }
                        },
                        Ban: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-danger',
                            text: 'Ban Account',
                            action: function () {
                                $.alert('Account has now been banned :(');
                            }
                        },
                        if(activated === '1'){
                        Deactivate: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-warning',
                            text: 'Deactivate Account',
                            action: function () {
                                $.alert('Account has now deactivted :(');
                            }
                        }
                        } else {
                        Deactivate: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-warning',
                            text: 'Activate Account',
                            action: function () {
                                $.alert('Account has now deactivted :(');
                            }
                        }
                        }
                        Reset: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-success',
                            text: 'Reset Password',
                            action: function () {
                                $.alert('User has been e-mailed a forgotten password link');
                            }
                        },
                        Close: {
                            btnClass: 'btn-default',
                            text: 'Close'
                        }   
                    }
                });
```

This code does not work presently, what would be a possible way of going about this?

Comment: this will help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12073352/use-confirm-as-a-condition-to-if

Comment: Sadly, I am not following what this means and how I can use it within the JConfirm Plugin